# How to structure ODEs in R based on multiple groups

Tags: r, ode

I am trying to simulate cell uptake in R, having ported a model from Berkeley Madonna. The model is comprised of several constants and differential equations to calculate amounts and concentrations. A portion of the code is listed:

```
library(deSolve)

fb = 0.0510
Km = 23.5
Pdif = 0.429
Vmax = 270
Vol_cell = 9.33
Vol_media = 150
S = 10 #concentration of dosing media

yini = c(Amt_media=(S*Vol_media)-(S*fb*Vol_cell), 
         Amt_cell=S*fb*Vol_cell, 
         Amt_total=S*Vol_media, 
         Con_media=S-(S*fb), 
         Con_cell=S*fb)

Uptake = function(t, y, p){
   dy1 = (- (Pdif * y[1]) + (Pdif * y[2]) - ((Vmax * y[4])/(Km + y[4]))) 
   dy2 = (+ (Pdif * y[1]) - (Pdif * y[2]) + ((Vmax * y[4])/(Km + y[4])))
   dy3 = dy1 + dy2
   dy4 = dy1 / Vol_media
   dy5 = dy2 / Vol_cell
   list(c(dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, dy5))}

times1 = seq(from=0, to=15, by=0.01)
out1 = ode(y=yini, times=times1, func=Uptake, parms=NULL, method="rk4")
```

The rest of the code is for output to dataframes and plotting. My question then is how to have the code structured to use "S" as a list of several concentrations such that each concentration can be applied to the differential equations (essentially giving me an out1 for S1, out2 for S2, etc, that can then be passed onto a dataframe)? In Berkeley Madonna this was achieved by writing over 35 differential equations, though I'd like to use a simplified approach in R if possible.

Comment: Write a function that takes `S` as a parameter, then use `lapply` to call it for many different values of `S`: `myfun<-function(S) {return S+1}; lapply(1:10, myfun)`. That will give you a list of output corresponding to each value of `S`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. I've been been pouring through SO and R documentation for for a few weeks now looking for exemplar code to incorporate into the model. Admittedly, I'm not quite sure how to implement your solution. Would your suggestion be incorporated into the "Uptake" function as a "with(parm...) or exist as a standalone function that forces "Uptake" into a loop to yield "out" for all the values of "S"?

Comment: `Uptake` doesn't seem to have any connection to `S`. you only seem to be using it in your `yini` vector. Are you just very new to programming? Is that the problem? Maybe a basic R tutorial might help with the basics on creating a function. I'm not sure I understand where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm fairly new to R (I've used its plotting & statistics output over the past year and am currently expanding into data fitting). In this model, `Uptake` is dependent upon `S` as it sets the initial conditions and governs the processes defined by `dy1` and `dy2`. If I include `S = c(1,3,10,30)`, the model will look for 20 differential equations rather than the 5 currently listed resulting in error, and I believe your code would prevent that. What I'm unsure is the syntax of the function that will iteratively calculate `Uptake` per the `S` list.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick! I had the `lapply` part correct per your first suggestion, but your ordering of the `runConc` function was the key. Thank you very kindly for the troubleshooting. Now I can map `out` to a dataframe for plotting. I intend to take this code and try fitting empirical `dy2` data to estimate several of the constants used in the original script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part where `S` is used is in the initialization of the `yini` values. Basically we just need to move that part and the part that runs `ode` with those values into a new function. Then you can call that function for what ever values you want. For example

```
#set up
library(deSolve)

fb <- 0.0510
Km <- 23.5
Pdif <- 0.429
Vmax <- 270
Vol_cell <- 9.33
Vol_media <- 150

Uptake <- function(t, y, p){
   dy1 = (- (Pdif * y[1]) + (Pdif * y[2]) - ((Vmax * y[4])/(Km + y[4]))) 
   dy2 = (+ (Pdif * y[1]) - (Pdif * y[2]) + ((Vmax * y[4])/(Km + y[4])))
   dy3 = dy1 + dy2
   dy4 = dy1 / Vol_media
   dy5 = dy2 / Vol_cell
   list(c(dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, dy5))}

times1 <- seq(from=0, to=15, by=0.01)

# function with S as a parameter
runConc <- function(S) {
  yini <- c(Amt_media=(S*Vol_media)-(S*fb*Vol_cell), 
    Amt_cell=S*fb*Vol_cell, 
    Amt_total=S*Vol_media, 
    Con_media=S-(S*fb), 
    Con_cell=S*fb)

    ode(y=yini, times=times1, func=Uptake, parms=NULL, method="rk4")
}

#run for concentrations 10,20,30
out <- lapply(c(10,20,30), runConc)
```

This will result in a list object with the results for each concentration. So `out[[1]]` is the result for S=10, `out[[2]]` is `S=20`, etc. We can see the first few lines of each of the results with

```
lapply(out, head, 3)

# [[1]]
#      time Amt_media Amt_cell Amt_total Con_media Con_cell
# [1,] 0.00  1495.242  4.75830      1500  9.490000 0.510000
# [2,] 0.01  1488.103 11.89710      1500  9.442408 1.275145
# [3,] 0.02  1481.028 18.97216      1500  9.395241 2.033457
# 
# [[2]]
#      time Amt_media Amt_cell Amt_total Con_media Con_cell
# [1,] 0.00  2990.483  9.51660      3000  18.98000 1.020000
# [2,] 0.01  2976.550 23.44980      3000  18.88711 2.513377
# [3,] 0.02  2962.739 37.26072      3000  18.79504 3.993646
# 
# [[3]]
#      time Amt_media Amt_cell Amt_total Con_media Con_cell
# [1,] 0.00  4485.725 14.27490      4500  28.47000  1.53000
# [2,] 0.01  4465.153 34.84653      4500  28.33286  3.73489
# [3,] 0.02  4444.761 55.23920      4500  28.19690  5.92060
```